# Problems with velocity and audio in pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame

Two things.  Can someone help me understand why the velocity doesn't go up?  I printed the vels and it does go up but something makes it go back down.  Also would be great if someone could tell me how to loop the music so it doesn't end.(space music). Let me know anything else if you want too.  I am making this game as notes because I am trying to learn more about python and pygame for a project that I am doing.  Let me know if you don't know what something is doing or are confused.  I didn't include the files because I don't think you really need to download it to figure it out but i can if needed.

```
import pygame
import random
from replit import audio

pygame.init()


bg = pygame.image.load("spacebg.png")
player = pygame.image.load("UFO.png")
obstacle = pygame.image.load("Asteroid.png")




highscore = 0
score = 0
counter = 0
multiplier = 1
level = 1

obstacle1x = random.randint(128,512)
obstacle1y = random.randint(128,512)
obstacle2x = random.randint(128,512)
obstacle2y = random.randint(128,512)
obstacle3x = random.randint(128,512)
obstacle3y = random.randint(128,512)



coinx = random.randint(128,512)
coiny = random.randint(128,512)


font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 30, True)


compwin = pygame.display.set_mode((512,512))

pygame.display.set_caption("RICH ALIEN DON'T DIE")
x=50
y=50
vel = 5

vel1 = random.randint(-5,5)
vel2 = random.randint(-5,5)
vel3 = random.randint(-5,5)
vel4 = random.randint(-5,5)
vel5 = random.randint(-5,5)
vel6 = random.randint(-5,5)


source1 = audio.play_file("space music.wav")



run = True
while run:
  
  pygame.time.delay(30)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run = False
  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  
  if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
    x-= vel
  if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]and x < 512 - 64 - vel:
    x+= vel
  if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel: 
    y-= vel
  if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 512 - 64 - vel:
    y+= vel

  hitbox1 = pygame.draw.rect(compwin,(0,0,0), (obstacle1x,obstacle1y,64,64) )
  hitbox2 = pygame.draw.rect(compwin,(0,0,0), (obstacle2x,obstacle2y,64,64) )
  hitbox3 = pygame.draw.rect(compwin,(0,0,0), (obstacle3x,obstacle3y,64,64) )
  hitbox = pygame.draw.rect(compwin,(0,0,0), (x,y,64,64) )
  
  compwin.blit(bg,(0,0))

  obstacle1x = obstacle1x +vel1
  obstacle1y = obstacle1y +vel2
  obstacle2x = obstacle2x +vel3
  obstacle2y = obstacle2y +vel4
  obstacle3x = obstacle3x +vel5
  obstacle3y = obstacle3y +vel6
  
  if obstacle1x < 0 or obstacle1x > 512 - vel1:
     vel1 = vel1 * -1
  if obstacle1y < 0 or obstacle1y > 512 - vel2:
     vel2 = vel2 * -1 
  if obstacle2x < 0 or obstacle2x > 512 - vel3:
     vel3 = vel3 * -1
  if obstacle2y < 0 or obstacle2y > 512 - vel4:
     vel4 = vel4 * -1
  if obstacle3x < 0 or obstacle3x > 512 - vel5:
     vel5 = vel5 * -1
  if obstacle3y < 0 or obstacle3y > 512 - vel6:
     vel6 = vel6 * -1
  


  compwin.blit(player,(x,y))

  compwin.blit(obstacle,(obstacle1x,obstacle1y))
  compwin.blit(obstacle,(obstacle2x,obstacle2y))
  compwin.blit(obstacle,(obstacle3x,obstacle3y))

  coin = pygame.draw.circle(compwin,(212,175,55),(coinx, coiny,),(16))
  if score > highscore:
    highscore = score
  text = font.render("Score: " +str(score), 1,(255,255,255))
  text2 = font.render("Highscore: " + str(highscore), 1, (255, 255, 255))
  text3 = font.render("Level: " +str(level), 1,(255,255,255))
  compwin.blit(text, (55, 10))
  compwin.blit(text2, (255, 10))
  compwin.blit(text3, (190, 482))
  if hitbox.colliderect(hitbox1) or hitbox.colliderect(hitbox2, ) or hitbox.colliderect(hitbox3):
   
    source = audio.play_file("mixkit-truck-crash-with-explosion-1616.wav")
    obstacle1x = random.randint(128,512)
    obstacle1y = random.randint(128,512)
    obstacle2x = random.randint(128,512)
    obstacle2y = random.randint(128,512)
    obstacle3x = random.randint(128,512)
    obstacle3y = random.randint(128,512)
  
    
    coinx = random.randint(128,512)
    coiny = random.randint(128,512)

 
    x=50
    y=50
    score = 0
    counter = 0
    multiplier = 1
    level = 1
  elif hitbox.colliderect(coin):
    score += multiplier
    counter+=1
    for i in [vel1,vel2,vel3,vel4,vel5,vel6]:
      print(i)
    coinx = random.randint(10,512)
    coiny = random.randint(10,512)
    if counter == 5:
      multiplier += 1
      counter = 0
      level+= 1
      for i in [vel1,vel2,vel3,vel4,vel5,vel6]:
        if i < 0:
          i += -1  
        else:
          i+= 1
          
  else:
    pygame.display.update()
    


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: `vel1`, `vel2` are integral values. Python has no concept of references. This values are assigned.

Comment: I am confused on what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Rabbid76 means is that, when doing this:

```py
for i in [vel1,vel2,vel3,vel4,vel5,vel6]:
   if i < 0:
      i += -1  
   else:
      i += 1
```

`i` becomes at each iteration a *copy* of `vel1`, `vel2`, and so on.
But `i` does not refer to these variables.  So basically, your loop
has no effect.  In other words it is equivalent to :

```py
i = vel1            #  copy vel1 in i
if i < 0: i += - 1  #  no effect on vel1
else: i += 1        #  no effect on vel1
i = vel2            #  copy vel2 in i
if i < 0: i += - 1  #  no effect on vel2
else: i += 1        #  no effect on vel2
...
```

Instead you can replace your `velI` variables by a list:

```py
vel_list = [
   random.randint(-5,5),
   random.randint(-5,5),
   random.randint(-5,5),
   random.randint(-5,5),
   random.randint(-5,5),
   random.randint(-5,5)
]
```

Your for loop can then be rewritten as:

```py
for i in range(len(vel_list)):
   if vel_list[i] < 0:
      vel_list[i] += -1  
   else:
      vel_list[i] += 1
```

Now this works because here `i` is an index to an item of your list.
So you directly update the item of your list rather than a copy.

Of course if you do that you will need to change in your program
`vel1` by `vel_list[0]`, `vel2` by `vel_list[1]` and so on.

Last thing: you can use *list comprehension* to simplify your code.

```py
#  initialisation
vel_list = [random.randint(-5,5) for x in range(5)]

#  update
vel_list = [v - 1 if v < 0 else v + 1 for v in vel_list]
```